# Segmentation fault (core dumped) when using fscanf in c

Tags: c, matrix, segmentation-fault, scanf

Segmentation fault (core dumped) occurred when I try to assign values from txt file to a matrix through fscanf. After getting into the inner for loop, the segmentation fault occurs. It prints `adj[0]` and `adj[0][0]`, and then segmentation fault(core dumped). Can someone help me figure it out?

```
int firstMin(int** adj, int i);
int secondMin(int** adj, int i);
void TSPRec(int** adj, int curr_bound, int curr_weight,
            int level, int curr_path[N], int visited[], int final_res, int final_path[]);
void TSP(int** adj, int child_node, int temp_path[N], int temp_res);

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    int best_res = INT_MAX;
    int best_path[N];
    int final_res = INT_MAX;
    int final_path[N];
    int i, m;
    int **adj = (int **)malloc(N * sizeof(int*));
    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
        adj[i] = (int *)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    for(i=0; i<N; i++){
        for(m=0; m<N; m++) adj[i][m] = 0;
    }
    int id;
    int temp_path[N];
    int temp_res;

    scanf("%d", &N);
    FILE *fp;
    char file_name[10] = {0};
    sprintf(file_name, "cities%d", N);
    strcat(file_name, ".txt");
    fp = fopen(file_name, "r");

    int a,b;
    for(a = 0; a < N; a++)
    {
        printf("adj[%d]\n", a);
        for(b = 0; b < N; b++)
        {
            printf("adj[%d][%d]\n", a, b);
            if (!fscanf(fp, "%d", &adj[a][b]))
                break;
            printf("finished\n");
            printf("%d", adj[a][b]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    fclose(fp);

    printf("\n");

    for(a = 0; a < N; a++)
    {
        for(b = 0; b < N; b++)
        {
            printf("%d", adj[a][b]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: declaration: the segmentation fault happens when fscanf is executed.

Comment: You seem to believe that declaring VLAs based on the suspiciously missing `N` (such as `int final_path[N];`, etc) then *later* reading `N` from a terminal via `scanf("%d", &N);` will somehow resize all those arrays. That isn't how VLAs work.

Comment: please learn how to use a debugger. Walking this code would show that you have empty arrays as the previous poster has noted.

Comment: I didn't mean to resize final_path[N], but just want to assign values to adj matrix.